# Google Big Query Streaming data error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm using the ([see here](https://github.com/StreakYC/mache)) to load our datastore logs to big query (BQ), and exporting datastore entities to big query runs fine however I'm stuck in streaming data to big query. The relevant line the error is pointing in BigQueryIngester.java:

```
response = bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(projectId, datasetId, tableId, content).execute();
```

It is raising a `NullPointerException` and I dont know what is wrong. Can somebody pls give me a hint

```
Uncaught exception from servlet java.lang.NullPointerException  at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator._writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:289)
    at
 com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8JsonGenerator.writeFieldName(UTF8JsonGenerator.java:179)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonGenerator.writeFieldName(JacksonGenerator.java:73)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:171)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:172)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:145)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:172)
    at
 com.google.api.client.json.JsonGenerator.serialize(JsonGenerator.java:106)
    at
 com.google.api.client.http.json.JsonHttpContent.writeTo(JsonHttpContent.java:78)
    at
 com.google.api.client.http.GZipEncoding.encode(GZipEncoding.java:49)
    at
 com.google.api.client.http.HttpEncodingStreamingContent.writeTo(HttpEncodingStreamingContent.java:51)
    at com.google.api.client.util.IOUtils.computeLength(IOUtils.java:113)
    at
 com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:917)
    at
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
    at
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
    at
 com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
    at
 com.streak.logging.utils.BigqueryIngester.streamingRowIngestion(BigqueryIngester.java:54)
    at
 com.streak.logging.analysis.LogExportDirectToBigqueryTask.doGet(LogExportDirectToBigqueryTask.java:178)
```

Comment: Please edit your question. It is a mess right now.

Comment: Sorry, I thought error logs are useful

Comment: They *are* but not in this format.

Comment: Full error log is moved in pastebin. http://pastebin.com/YMCfCvwe :-)

Comment: Don't expect us to click on links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the error is in writing one of the field names in the json request. It is likely something is wrong with your rows. It might be that you have nested data that is not parseable, or you have a missing key for the name-object map. Can you print out an example and add it to the question or your pastebin link?

Comment: I put a logging before calling bigquery.tabledata().insertAll(): System.out.println("content: " + content.toPrettyString()); and one of the keys in json is null. So you're right. I traced the null value down to the field exporter getFieldName(int i) that returns null and change it to return field name in string. That fixed it.